# bash find keyword in an associative array

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have incoming messages from a chat server that need to be compared against a list of keywords. I was using regular arrays, but would like to switch to associative arrays to try to increase the speed of the processing.

The list of words would be in an array called aWords and the values would be a 'type' indicator, i.e. aWords[damn]="1", with 1 being *swear word* in a legend to inform the user.

The issue is that I need to compare every index value with the input $line looking for substrings. I'm trying to avoid a loop thru each index value if at all possible.

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html, I'm thinking of the Substring Removal section.

```
${string#substring}
Deletes shortest match of $substring from front of $string.
```

A comparison of the 'removed' string from the $line, may help, but will it match also words in the middle of other words? i.e. matching the keyword *his* inside of *this*.

Sorry for the long-winded post, but I tried to cover all of what I'm attempting to accomplish as best I could.

Comment: Data processing is not a strong point of `bash`, or indeed most shell languages. Consider using a language better suited to this task, like Python, Perl, or Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
# create a colon-separated string of the array keys
# you can do this once, after the array is created.
keys=$(IFS=:; echo "${!aWords[*]}")

if [[ ":$keys:" == *:"$word":* ]]; then
    # $word is a key in the array
    case ${aWords[$word]} in
        1) echo "Tsk tsk: $word is a swear word" ;;
        # ...
    esac
fi
```

Comment: if `aWords` is already an associative array, why not use it directly as `[[ ${aWords[$word]} = 1 ]]`? (I guess I really missed something here).

Comment: I'm liking this idea so far.  Some of the keywords are actually phrases, so I need to insert some "" in your example maybe? I suspect the spaces add a little something to the mix.

Comment: I think it's OK as is: `declare -A foo=(["bar baz"]=yes); x="bar baz"; echo ${foo[$x]}`

Comment: there appears to be a bug when assigning more than one item to an array with a parenthesis enclosed list if any of the keys have spaces in them. http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays . I don't know if that is still the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I heard of associative arrays in bash. It inspired me to also try to add something, with the chance ofcourse that I completely miss the point.

Here is a code snippet. I hope I understood how it works:

```
declare -A SWEAR       #create associative array of swearwords (only once)
while read LINE
do
        [ "$LINE"] && SWEAR["$LINE"]=X
done < "/path/to/swearword/file"


while : 
do
    OUTGOING=""        #reset output "buffer"
    read REST          #read a sentence from stdin
    while "$REST"      #evaluate every word in the sentence
    do
        WORD=${REST%% *}
        REST=${REST#* }
        [ ${SWEAR[$WORD]} ] && WORD="XXXX"
        OUTGOING="$OUTGOING $WORD"
    done
    echo "$OUTGOING"    #output to stdout
done
```

Comment: It would be altogether simpeler if I was allowed to throw away complete lines on a dirty word :-)   `dirty_message | grep -wvif swearwordfile | clean_message`